# How do I alter the background color so that it fits inside the CircularPercentIndicator?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to alter it so that the area within the Circle gets colored, but not the entire square as shown below. I used `fillColor` to change the background,

Here's what I have

[image]

Here's my goal

[image]

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Obx(
      () {
        if (settingsController
            .user.value.kicks.isNotEmpty) {
          var totalKicks = settingsController
              .user.value.kicks.length;
          var goalsArea = settingsController
              .user.value.kicks[1].kickArea;
          return CircularPercentIndicator(
            radius: 20.0,
            lineWidth: 2.0,
            percent: goalsArea / totalKicks,
            backgroundColor:
                Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
            progressColor:
                Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
            center: Text(
              ((goalsArea / totalKicks) * 100)
                      .toInt()
                      .toString() +
                  "%",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(
                    255, 0, 0, 0),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return CircularPercentIndicator(
            fillColor: Color.fromARGB(
                255, 206, 175, 138),
            radius: 20.0,
            lineWidth: 2.0,
            percent: 0,
            backgroundColor:
                Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
            progressColor:
                Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
            center: Text(
              "0%",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(
                    255, 0, 0, 0),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
      child: Text(
        "Left 5m Channel",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 7,
          color: Colors.grey[400],
          background: Paint()
            ..strokeWidth = 8.5
            ..color =
                Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)
            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your `CircularPercentIndicator` with a `ClipRRect` widget using the same radius.

### Code Sample

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  child: CircularPercentIndicator(
    fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 206, 175, 138),
    radius: 20.0,
    lineWidth: 2.0,
    percent: 0,
    backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
    progressColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
    center: const Text(
      "0%",
      style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
    ),
  ),
)
```

### Screenshot

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your CircularPercentIndicator with a ClipOval widget.

```
             ClipOval(
                    child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                    fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 206, 175, 138),
                    radius: 20.0,
                    lineWidth: 2.0,
                    percent: 0,
                    backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                    progressColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                    center: const Text(
                      "0%",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```